# Prevent drop down from closing onclick after letting go of mouse key

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I have a drop down menu that was a hover on drop down menu.  I changed the hover portion of the css to active and changed the hover to click in the script.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('header li.full-width').click(function () {
        $('.site-content').addClass('overlay');

    });

    // Reveal/Hide Mobile sub menus.
    $('body .main-navigation ul.menu > li.menu-item-has-children > .caret').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('dropdown-open');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I was able to obtain the open on click functionality but it only stays open while I am pressing in the mousekey.  As soon as I depress the mouse button the menu closes.

How can I get it to stay open on click and only close when I click again.

Comment: change `click` to `mouseover`

Comment: Add HTML and CSS to your post so that the code can be tested